# Get My Photo Uploaded in Instagram using Instagram API

Tags: ios, api, instagram

what is the URL to get your own photos instagram not the newsfeed.
I can get JSON data but it is the newsfeed. I just need my uploaded photos. Pls. help thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the url given below

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent

This url bring photos you uploaded